# searchbar not showing on Ionic

Tags: java, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to make a fixed searchbar on top of my screen under the tab bar for android and under the navbar for ios.

I'm using the docs: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/

Ionic version: 2.1.12

But my searchbar isn't showing.

My code:

HTML:

```
<ion-view title="Search" id="page3" hide-nav-bar="isAndroid">
    <div class="bar bar-subheader bar-positive item-input-inset" no-tap-scroll="true">
        <ion-searchbar
            [(ngModel)]="search"
            [showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel"
            (ionInput)="handleSearch($event)">
        </ion-searchbar>
    </div>
    <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="doc in documents" item="doc">
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see no searchbar appears...

I tried putting it in between other components in my views but it doesn't appear either. The docs don't explain anything on this subject. Very frustrating

Answer (score 1):

http://plnkr.co/edit/dPsGZjczRSNpqmMDqLZQ?p=info

This is the code you provided, if you remove all `<br/>` tags in the plunker you will see that the searchbar is shoved behind the header.

[image]

So adding a `style="z-index:999999999999"` (just to be sure) to the `<ion-searchbar>` resulted in this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JE1Vm47ehXsmkp5s9PGZ?p=info

[image]

Comment: Would it be this simple I'd probably have it figured out, but it's not this... unfortunately

Comment: @HelderJulesDeBaere then post more code please, this is the solution for the code you posted.